# Application runs into a Redirect Loop error WildFly8

Tags: jboss, wildfly-8

I was trying to migrate the server from Jboss 4.2.2 to WildFly-8.2.0. Facing some issues while deploying the war file. War is getting deployed, but url rewriting creates issues.

For 4.2.2 the same had been written in a file called `rewrite.properties` in side the localhost folder.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(.*)[.]([a-zA-Z]+)$
RewriteRule ^/home/(.*)$ /home/index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

As per some documentations, I cam to know that we can create a `undertow-handlers.conf` to my ROOT.war/WEB-INF/ folder, and

how can I put the above in regex[]  format in 'undertow-handlers.conf'

tried this

`regex['/home/(.*)$'] -> rewrite['/home/index.php']`

It seems the url is correctly loading and redirecting to the home page. But application runs into a Redirect Loop error. I was referring [this](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=995559)
and [this](https://help.openshift.com/hc/en-us/articles/202398810) docs. It seems we can configure http connector to prevent redirect loop like this:

```
<connector name="http" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="http" socket-binding="http" proxy-name="${env.OPENSHIFT_GEAR_DNS}" proxy-port="443" secure="true"/>
```

But I dont know how to configure this in WildFly 8. 
Secondly, if this issue is due to the missing of RewriteCond in the new regex in 'undertow-handlers.conf'?

```
ERROR:
[io.undertow.request] (default task-20) UT005023: Exception handling request to /home/index.php?q=: com.caucho.quercus.QuercusModuleException: java.io.IOException:
```

An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Please help me out to resolve this issues.

My web.xml:

```
<servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>Quercus Servlet</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>*.php</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>

 <welcome-file-list>
   <welcome-file>index.php</welcome-file>
 </welcome-file-list>
```

Answer (score 4):

The undertow equivalent to the rewrite conditions would be:

```
regex['/home/(.*)$'] -> rewrite['/home/index.php?q=${1}']
```

And I'm pretty sure the exception is not related to the regex itself.

Comment: There is no specific error, I have a doubt, whether the looping redirection is due to the missing of this condition `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(.*)[.]([a-zA-Z]+)$` from WildFly.